# Choice of tense following "I wish it was true that..."

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses, tense-agreement

Which is correct?

> I wish it was true that I don't love you.

OR

> I wish it was true that I didn't love you.

I am talking in the present time, trying to express that I am not happy as a result of my love for you after its hurtful times in the past and still now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use past tense forms to talk about [wishes](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/wishes-and-hypotheses), even if the consequences are in the present, so the second sentence is better. Strictly speaking, you should use **were** rather than **was**, although  in everyday usage **was** is nearly as common.

> I wish it **were** true that I didn't love you.

"I wish it **were** true" is a way of disagreeing with something that somebody has just said, so it is appropriate if the other person has just said "You don't love me".

If this isn't part of a conversation and you are simply expressing a wish, you would probably say

> I wish that I didn't love you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a sentence where you could find both possibilities:

1 I wish it was true that I don't love you (referring to the situation now).

2 I wish it was true that I didn't love you (referring to a time past).

But as a non-native speaker I'm not quite sure whether I'm right. I would like to have comments by other posters.